# React Native Flatlist inside ScrollView

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to develop a profile screen which has the persons profile pic, name, etc in the header as well as tabs that determines which data gets displayed in the FlatList below.  I want the header component to be scrollable with the FlatList so that the header does not take up screen space while scrolling the FlatList.  Also, the header's tabs will change the data that gets render in the list.  I have tried two approaches but neither one has worked.  Including the header and flatlist inside of a scrollview causes the flatlist to continually call onEndReach until all of the data is returned, but I also read that this is not recommended.  The second approach was setting the ListHeaderComponent on the flatlist to the header component, but every time a tab is change the entire screen reloads.  I am looking to have the header scrollable as if it were part of the flatlist, and only the flatlist re-render when a tab is pressed.  Similar to what Instagram has with their profile screen.  Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.